# Vector Space of bounded linear operators is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The following is Ch4 Ex18(c) of *Stein's Real Analysis / Measure Theory*.

> **Exercise 4.18(c)** Let $\mathcal H$ denote a Hilbert space and $\mathcal L(H)$ the vector space of all bounded linear operator on $\mathcal H$. Show that $\mathcal L(H)$ is complete in the metric $d$, where $d(T_1,T_2) = ||T_1 - T_2||$.

This is what I've done. ($\Vert\cdot \Vert$ implies $\Vert\cdot \Vert_{\mathcal H}$)

Let{$T_n$} be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal L(H)$; for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb N$ such that $m,n \ge N_{\epsilon}$ implies $\Vert T_m - T_n \Vert < \epsilon$

$\Vert(T_m-T_n)f\Vert \le \Vert T_m-T_n\Vert \Vert f\Vert$ for every $f \in \mathcal H$, so $m,n \ge N_{\epsilon}$ implies $\Vert T_mf-T_nf \Vert \le \Vert f\Vert\epsilon$.

So, {$T_nf$} is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal H$. Then, there is $F \in \mathcal H$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Vert T_nf - F\Vert = 0$. Let $F = T(f)$.

-editted-
If this is correct, it remains to show that $T$ is bounded, linear, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n = T$. Except for the linearity, I have a difficulty solving these points.

Any help about this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You also need to show/justify that $T$ is linear, though that's not too hard. Hint for the boundedness: write $\|T(f)\| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|T_n(f)\|$.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask one more question, which is added in the main question above? I found out that I also need to show that lim$_n||Tn-T|| = 0$. If this is correct, is there some ideas about the convergence of $T_n$ to $T$? Btw, now I guess I can handle the bounded of $T$ using the hint.

Comment: You can fix $n$ and take the limit when $m$ goes to infinity in $\| T_m(f) - T_n(f) \| \leq \epsilon \|f\|$. (btw you can use `\|` instead of double bars for norms, it'll look neater)

Comment: Ah, Ok I got it. Thank you very much!